# Apache Ignite .Net : KeyNotFoundException occurs when using multi-PK

Tags: .net, ignite, ddl, gridgain, keynotfoundexception

I use gridgain Ignite community 8.8.31(it is same at apache ignite 2.15), and I made two tables using DDL.(Insert data with DML)
When I try to cache.get() using C#/.NET, Person3 has error but Person4 is runs well.
These two tables are exactly same except Primary Key name.

I wonder why this happen.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person3 (
ID int,
CITY_ID int,
NAME varchar,
AGE int,
COMPANY varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (ID, CITY_ID)
) WITH "template=REPLICATED,CACHE_NAME=Person3,KEY_TYPE=test.PersonKey3,VALUE_TYPE=test.PersonValue3";

INSERT INTO Person3 VALUES (1,1,'1',1,'1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person4 (
CITY_ID int,
CITY_ID_2 int,
NAME varchar,
AGE int,
COMPANY varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (CITY_ID, CITY_ID_2)
) WITH "template=REPLICATED,CACHE_NAME=Person4,KEY_TYPE=test.PersonKey4,VALUE_TYPE=test.PersonValue4";

INSERT INTO Person4 VALUES (1,1,'1',1,'1');
```

My .NET code is below.

```
namespace test
{
    class PersonKey3
    {
        [QuerySqlField]
        public int ID, CITY_ID;
    }

    class PersonValue3 : PersonKey3
    {
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string NAME, COMPANY;

        [QuerySqlField]
        public int AGE;
    }

    class PersonKey4
    {
        [QuerySqlField]
        public int CITY_ID, CITY_ID_2;
    }

    class PersonValue4 : PersonKey4
    {
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string NAME, COMPANY;

        [QuerySqlField]
        public int AGE;
    }

    class IgniteTest
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IgniteClientConfiguration cfg = new IgniteClientConfiguration
            {
                Endpoints = new[] { "127.0.0.1:10800" }
            };

            using (var client = Ignition.StartClient(cfg))
            {
                client.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(PersonKey3));
                client.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(PersonValue3));

                client.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(PersonKey4));
                client.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(PersonValue4));

                /*runs well*/
                var cache4 = client.GetCache<PersonKey4, PersonValue4>("Person4");
                PersonKey4 tableKey4 = new PersonKey4();
                tableKey4.CITY_ID = 1;
                tableKey4.CITY_ID_2 = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(cache4.Get(tableKey4).COMPANY);

                /*error!*/
                var cache3 = client.GetCache<PersonKey3, PersonValue3>("Person3");
                PersonKey3 tableKey3 = new PersonKey3();
                tableKey3.ID = 1;
                tableKey3.CITY_ID = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(cache3.Get(tableKey3).COMPANY);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

error message is below

```
Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the cache.
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.UnmarshalNotNull[T](ClientResponseContext ctx)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.<Get>b__14_0(ClientResponseContext ctx)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DecodeResponse[T](BinaryHeapStream stream, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.DoOutInOpAffinity[T,TKey](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Int32 cacheId, TKey key, Func`3 errorFunc)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.DoOutInOpAffinity[T](ClientOp opId, TK key, Func`2 readFunc)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.Get(TK key)
   at test.IgniteTest.Main() in E:\GHLee\dev\cs\GridgainTest\Program.cs:line 119
```

Comment: `Person3 has error` - please provide full error message with stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` should have key fields in alphabetical order. Put `CITY_ID` before `ID` to make it work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person3 (
                CITY_ID int,
                ID int,
                NAME varchar,
...
```

**Explanation:**

- Ignite uses hashing to locate keys
- Hash is computed from serialized key representation
- Serializer always sorts fields by name
- SQL engine seems to use the original order, so there is a hash miss

Looks like a bug to me, I'll check if there is a ticket.